# Connecting C++ with QML using Q_INVOKABLE

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-slot

I have a Qt function:

```
void MainWindow::button_clicked(Qstring a, Qstring b, Qstring c, Qstring d)
```

I collect data from QML and I want to pass data to this function which is in Qt. So I know I need to use `Q_INVOKABLE` but don't know really how to use it.

And one more thing is it possible to invoke some other function when invoke this certain above.
For example: I invoke the above function but in her body I invoke `refresh()` function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To be able to call a method from QML, you must either mark it with Q_INVOKABLE or as a slot. I prefer Q_INVOKABLE if it's not meant to be used as a slot, as its more minimal.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
...
    Q_INVOKABLE void buttonClicked( const QString& a, const QString& b, const QString& c, const QString& d );
....
};

void MainWindow::buttonClicked( const QString& a, const QString& b, const QString& c, const QString& d ) {
   ...do stuff
   update(); //example
}
```

The implementation of buttonClicked() can contain any C++ code.

To make the main window instance accessible from QML, you must register it, e.g.

```
QDeclarativeView* view = ...your view
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty( "_mainWindow", mainWindow );
```

Once registered, you can call buttonClicked from QML:

```
_mainWindow.buttonClicked("foo", "bar", "c", "d")
```

Comment: hi I have this in mainwindow.cpp : `QDeclarativeView *view= new QDeclarativeView;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setCentralWidget(view);
    QDeclarativeContext *ctxt = view->rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(MainWindow::dataList));


     view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gui.qml"));
     view->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);` so how to put your line inside? In main.cpp I only create mainwindow and call show method.

Comment: It probably would be ctxt->setContextProperty( "_mainWindow", this ); then.

Comment: Akiva: With "registering" I meant setting it as context property on the root context, as done in the snippet that follows above.